# Silent failure on UploadFromStreamAsync to Azure Storage

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, azure-storage, asp.net-core-2.2, azure-blob-storage

I am uploading an email to Azure Storage and I got the process failing without any error thrown when I call `UploadFromStreamAsync`

Here is the full function:

```
    public async Task<string> UploadFileToStorage(IFormFile photo, AzureStorageConfig _storageConfig)
    {
        CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(_storageConfig.ConnectionString);
        CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
        CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference(_storageConfig.ImageContainer);
        var fileName = photo.FileName;
        CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(fileName);
        blockBlob.Properties.ContentType = GetContentType(photo.FileName);
        blockBlob.Properties.CacheControl = "max-age=31536000";

        using (var stream = photo.OpenReadStream())
        {
            // Upload the file
            //await blockBlob.UploadFromByteArrayAsync(ReadFully(stream, blockBlob.StreamWriteSizeInBytes), 0, (int)stream.Length);
            await blockBlob.UploadFromStreamAsync(stream);
        }
        return await Task.FromResult(fileName);
    }
```

It works fine on my colleague machine, he uses 5.7 storage emulator, I am using 5.10. Not sure the emulator version could be an issue? Or something else? Cos the emulator is running fine.

I have it in .NET Core 2.2.0 solution.

Comment: `.NET 2.2.0 soclution`? You meant .Net-Core? Also if the function is async-await there is really no need for `return await Task.FromResult(fileName);` if something is already awaited just return the result `return fileName;`

Comment: The reason maybe that the storage emulator 5.10 is the latest one, but your storage client library for blob is old. You can try to use the latest storage client library for blob [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Blob/).

Answer (score 0):

One possible reason is that the blob storage client library is old in your side.

Please take a try the latest version of blob storage client library [Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Blob 11.0.1](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Blob/) with storage emulator 5.10.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this removing the await and using .Wait() after UploadFromStreamAsync(stream). incredible but true.
Obviously you cannot use an async method.

Comment: How is this obvious?